# How create a Wordpress template through a HTML/CSS page?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I would like to learn about wordpress.

Is possible to create a wordpress template through a HTML/CSS page ?
I'm taking an easy HTML page to start, so I install the XAMPP and then the lastest Wordpress.
Any help is very welcome.

Thank you very much.
ps: I'm searching something in Google though.

Comment: [Probably the best there is.](http://digwp.com/)

Comment: and didn't get any results in google search?

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/73-wordpress-theme/ Chris Coyier of DIGWP.com did a three part screencast on this. This is the third part, when he converts the HTML/CSS he has into a wordpress theme.

Comment: this one is the best http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wordpress-theme-development-training-wheels-day-one/

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend learning a bit of PHP since it really helps making your way around Wordpress files. Makes life a lot easier even if you're mainly editing HMTL/CSS.

Answer (score 0):

- Install Wordpress
- Copy the defaut theme folder (twenty elevent) inside /wp-content/themes
- Rename the folder to your theme
- Open style.css inside it and change meta information in the header file
- Edit away the php/style sheets as you like to modify the theme to match your style
- header.php - contains the common header code, usually navigation etc (Edit everything but dont remove wp_header. You will need that tag for wordpress to work, same for wp_footer in footer.php)
- index.php is the main content file, sidebar.php is the sidebar
- But you can use all these files as you please, its normal php/mysql stuff.

  - This is very useful too - http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates